# Do I need the build log file for my c# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I build my C# Winforms project in VS2017 I get the following warning

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 
that could not be resolved.  
These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is 
set to detailed.
```

I found where I could set the verbosity to detailed using Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run

Do I really need the build file, since I do get more information in the output window when I change the verbosity?

If so where do I find it?

The output window states

```
3>Building with tools version "15.0".
3>Project file contains ToolsVersion="12.0". This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="15.0". For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293424.
3>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\devvm\git\SBD.JobTalk.MyobApi\MYOBAPITests\MYOBAPITests.csproj" (target "BeforeRebuild" depends on it):
3>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
3>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
3>Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
3>Task "Message"
3>  Configuration=Debug
3>Done executing task "Message".
3>Task "Message"
3>  Platform=AnyCPU
3>Done executing task "Message".
3>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\Debug\')).
3>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\')).
3>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\Debug\')).
3>Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "MYOBAPITests.csproj".
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this two MSDN articles

[How to: View, Save, and Configure Build Log Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx)

[Obtaining Build Logs with MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx)

Comment: This link seems to be for C++ projects

Answer (score 0):

I did actually manage to solve my problem using the information in the output window, so I am guessing that locating the log file is not necessary if one is building from within the IDE. That is that the output window gives as much information as the log file.

Comment: By default when building from the IDE it does not output to a log file. It only does it when you build from MSBuild or other command line building methods. The reason the option for log file verbosity in settings is for C++ project's log files.

Comment: The verbosity settings also seem to effect the C# output window.  I think I needed the verbosity to solve my problem. I will double check when I am back on my dev pc.